# Работа не волк () в лес не убежит.

Tags: пунктуация

В этом предложении обычно ставится запятая или тире. Кроме того, по-разному понимается  смысл пословицы: (1) не торопись выполнять работу (она никуда не денется); (2) все равно придется ее выполнять (так что лучше выполнить сразу).

Вопросы: Какой смысл имеет пословица? Можно ли при ее оформлении использовать двоеточие? Как объяснить  выбор каждого знака и  связан ли он с разным смыслом пословицы?

ОДНО ИЗ МНЕНИЙ  http://shefdostal.org/poleznye-stati/171-rabota-ne-volk-v-les-ne-ubezhit.html

"Есть, правда, еще одна пословица, которая как бы стоит особняком от остальных – «работа не волк - в лес не убежит». Многие из нас привыкли считать, что ее смысл заключается в том, что не стоит спешить сделать что-то, что вполне может подождать. Некоторые рассматривают данную мысль как доказательство того, что русский народ на редкость ленив и не отрицает этого. Однако как было сказано выше, наши предки попросту бы не выжили, если бы позволяли себе лениться. Так откуда же у трудолюбивых людей подобные мысли?

Дело в том, что пословица «работа не волк - в лес не убежит», уже по традиции, часто трактуется неверно. Она означает не необязательность выполнения чего-либо, а то, что хочешь - не хочешь, а делать придется. У работы ведь нет ног, она просто так не встанет с места и никуда не денется. Она – не волк, который полежал, отдохнул, встал – и нет его. С работой всё по-другому: сама по себе она не исчезнет".

Comment: Оба  толкования  логичны. Но  и  традиции  толкований  учитывать  надо.  Весь  русский  народ  здесь  ни  при  чём.  Пословиц - море.  Лентяи  тоже  право  имеют  внести  свою  лепту  в  пословичный  фонд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раньше эта пословица звучала чуть по-другому : "Работа не медведь, в лес не уйдет". Даль не раскрывает ее значения, видимо, оно было общеизвестным. Откроем том Мамина-Сибиряка, почитаем сказку "Упрямый козел" :

> Столяр и сам видел, что всё у него идет из рук вон плохо, - не смотрел бы ни на что. Особенно тошно ему делалось по вечерам... Начал столяр уходить вечерами из дому куда-нибудь в соседи. Все-таки на людях как будто и повеселее, то есть даже и не веселее, а время как-то незаметно проходит. Глядишь, вечера и нет; а тут, глядишь, и спать пора... Прежде столяр работал по вечерам, а теперь работа лежала на полке.
>
> **- Успею как-нибудь, - утешал он самого себя. - Работа не медведь - в лес не уйдет!**

Значение народной пословицы становится понятным. Запятая или тире в ней - не имеет значения.

Как понимали сабж в 19 веке отечественные писатели :

> Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона
>
> дело не волк(медведь), в лес(не убежит) не уйдет 
> дело не волк(медведь), в лес(не убежит) не уйдет
> (поспеет!)
> Дело не воробей (не сокол), не улетит.
> Ср. По-видимому... вы никогда не будете заниматься делом. "Отчего же? Дело не медведь, в лес не уйдет".
> А.П. Чехов. Дуэль. 3.
> Ср. "Я на следствие". — Я ведь знаю эти следствия: это именно та самая вещь, об которой сложилась русская пословица: дело не волк, в лес не убежит...
> Салтыков. Губернские очерки. 7. Лузгин.
> Ср. Что же так-с (ехать)? **часом раньше, часом позже — дело не волк, в лес не уйдет.** Заодно уж у нас покушаете, а после обеда и в путь-с.
> Салтыков. Невинные рассказы. Святочный рассказ. 2.
> Ср. Коли у меня есть где дело, так я бывало знаю, что дело не медведь, в лес не уйдет: его можно положить или даже забыть без умысла, либо пустить другое наперед, оно и лежит... а между тем его же можно кончить в один день ...
> В.И. Даль. Небывалое в былом. 5.

Comment: Спасибо, интересный материал. Скорее всего, Мамин-Сибиряк излагал  общепринятую версию "ленивых".  И еще о знаках. Согласно классической орографии, тире ставится, когда первая часть БСП имеет значение причины, а вторая - следствия. Получается следующее: "Так как работа не волк, то она в лес не убежит". Главная часть - это то, что не убежит (не торопись ее делать). А если поставить запятые, то направленность причинно-следственных отношений  НЕ ОБОЗНАЧЕНА, можно толковать пословицу различным образом.

Comment: Вот пример: "Как-то я попытался сострить, добавив два слова к известной пословице: «Работа не волк, в лес не уйдет, не надейся» (Феликс Кривин).

Answer (score 1):

Дело тут вовсе не в лени. Бывает так, что всё "с рук валиться", работа не идёт, инструмент ломается, человек нервничает, но продолжает упорствовать. Именно в такой момент ему просто необходим совет об отдыхе и о том, что данную работу следует отложить до более благоприятного момента. Данная пословица и является поэтической формой такого совета: "Отдохни, расслабься! **Работа не волк - в лес не убежит!**"

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что эта пословица отражает не трудолюбие или лень народа, а его склонность к философско-художественному  осмыслению окружающего мира. Работа никуда не денется, и человек в соответствии со своим характером и ситуацией делает из этого вывод: сделать быстро, отложить до завтра, отдохнуть  и  приняться за работу снова.